# Como eu pego uma variável em outro método?

Tags: java, variáveis, método

Declarei uma variável dentro da classe `Main` e quero usar ela dentro de um método, como eu coloco ela lá?

```
public class Main {
   static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
   Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
   String[] disciplinas = new String[5];
   int numeroDisciplinas = 0;

 public static void cadastrarDisciplina(){
        numeroDisciplinas +1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tentou usar getters e setters ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028967/simple-getter-setter-comments

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem duas estratégias e depende do que deseja.

Você deve comunicar o valor através do método, passo ela como argumento e recebo como parâmetro e retorno o valor alterado para quem chamou. Algo assim:

```
public class Main {
    static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno();
    String[] disciplinas = new String[5];
    int numeroDisciplinas = 0;
    numeroDisciplinas = cadastrarDisciplina(numeroDisciplinas);
}

public static int cadastrarDisciplina(int numeroDisciplinas) {
    return numeroDisciplinas + 1; //espero que faça mais que isto, não faz sentido só ter essa linha
}
```

Pra ser sincero neste código não parece o mais adequado, porém o código todo não parece muito adequado. Então pode ser queria criar esta variável fora dos métodos e ela tendo o escopo da classe todos os métodos podem acessá-la. Mas se fizer com uma variável deve fazer com as outras, certo?

```
static int numeroDisciplinas = 0;
static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
static String[] disciplinas = new String[5];

public class Main {
    Aluno aluno = new Aluno(); //espero que isto seja usado adequadamente, quem sabe deva estar fora também
    cadastrarDisciplina(numeroDisciplinas);
}

public static void cadastrarDisciplina() {
    numeroDisciplinas + 1;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/ClassMembers.java).

Parece mais adequado, certo? Mas eu não iria nisto tão rápido, funciona, mas em código real dificilmente você faria isto e está aprendendo errado. É claro que entendendo melhor o problema pode ser até que possa ser útil em outro cenário.

Eu ainda acho que todo o código está ruim e está só tentando arrumar um um problema por esse código ser ruim, se fizer ele de uma forma melhor não teria esse problema. Não da para ajudar mais que isto porque precisaria entender todos os detalhes do problema. Em geral as pessoas que estão aprendendo a programar costumam ter mais problemas de entendimento do problema do que da programação em si. Foco nisto.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, a ideia do meu código é usar o numeroDisciplinas para limitar o cadastro ao preencher os 5 espaços do vetor, eu cortei um pedaço do código pra deixar só a duvida em si, mas acho que isso não vai resolver meu problema, eu quero executar o cadastrarDisciplina normalmente e sempre que for executado ele, somar +1 no numeroDisciplina ate o if parar, olha só https://pastebin.com/rbz8jPyX

Answer (score 0):

Você pode passar a variável para a função `cadastrarDisciplina` por meio de um parametro.

> "um parâmetro é um valor, proveniente de uma variável ou de uma expressão mais complexa, que pode ser passado para uma sub-rotina." [Parâmetro (ciência da computação)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Par%C3%A2metro_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o))

Na sua função você deve passar `numeroDisciplinas` e retornar o valor dessa variavel + 1, assim você pegar o número de disciplinas mais um.

```
public static int cadastrarDisciplina(int numeroDisciplinas){
        return numeroDisciplinas + 1;
    }
}
```